# Почему такой результат при конвертации из RGB в HSV/HLS с OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, rgb

Возьмем точку чисто зеленого цвета в формате RGB, преобразуем ее в HSV формат с использованием OpenCV:

```
green = np.uint8([[[0, 255, 0]]])
hsv_green = cv2.cvtColor(green, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv_green)
```

не забываем, что OpenCV последовательно везде использует BGR, но это сейчас неважно, так как значение имеет только составляющая R.
Мы увидим, что значение чисто зеленого цвета после преобразования ==> [[[60 255 255]]]
но вообще-то должно было быть [[[120 255 255]]]
нетрудно убедиться, если посмотреть:
https://www.peko-step.com/en/tool/hsvrgb_en.html
или
[здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp)

причем, после преобразования с помощью cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV составляюшая 'H' всегда на 50% меньше того значения, которое должно быть, например для синего (если BGR[255,0,0]) преобразование дает [[[120 255 255]]], а должно быть [[[240 255 255]]], а для желтого (если BGR[0,255,255]) получается [[[30 255 255]]], и лишь для чистого красного (BGR[0,0,255]) дает правильное значение HSV [[[0 255 255]]].

Comment: «составляюшая 'H' всегда на 50% меньше того значения, которое должно быть» — собственно, именно это и написано в [документации OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html) — «For HSV, hue range is [0,179]»

Comment: "For HSV, hue range is [0,179], saturation range is [0,255], and value range is [0,255]."

Странно, но 179 это не 50% от 255... 
Т.е. получаем значение пикселей в формате HSV и чтобы правильно оценить, например, дисперсию цвета, умножаем значение H всех пикселей на 2? При этом составляющие "S" и "L" выражаются в значениях [0,255].
Странная логика, в чем смысл?

Comment: Смысл в том, что диапазон [0,359] не влезает в один байт

Comment: Спасибо!  Действительно, ведь 180 это половина от 360 )